# command line arguments make file

Tags: command-line, makefile, command-line-arguments

So I know how to create variables and store values from command line.

But normally, I would type my command this way: make run VAR="abc", and VAR will be assigned the new value "abc"

However, if I want to do something like this VAR="abc" make run, how can I change my make file? Right now, if I run this, VAR still has the initial value when it was created in the make file.

This is my make file:

```
VAR = ""

.PHONY : build run

build : program.c
   gcc -o prog -g program.c

run : build
   ./prog $(VAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `VAR = ""`, you're overwriting any value `VAR` might have had (e.g. from the environment, or the command line). You can use a conditional assignment instead, which looks like this:

```
VAR ?= ""
```

This sets `VAR` only if it wasn't set already. It's equivalent to e.g.

```
ifeq ($(origin VAR), undefined)
  VAR = ""
endif
```

Comment: The make manual link discusses `?=` (and gives that equivalent code) in [The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

Comment: Also, just for the record `VAR = ""` in make isn't setting `VAR` to an empty string it is setting it to the value `""`. Which is strictly less useful than an empty string to make itself and so really doesn't have any useful purpose and should likely just be dropped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR = ${VAR}
```

if i remember right